# How to hit sonarQube api with username and api token in postman.(bearer token and username password is working Problem with UserName and Api Token)

Tags: api, sonarqube, postman, token, unauthorized

In Postman i'm giving SonarQube Api 
like 
http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?projectKeys=project1&tags=duplicate
And in Type i'm Taking Basic Auth

and after i'm giving userName and Api Token
Like : admin:5d984b57b0575e2dd088d02c9cc596e9b9600457
in that time it's giving 401-Unauthorized

so please share your experience with me.

NOTE :- **With this Api Token In postman Username Password and Bearer Token it's Working . i'm facing Unauthorized issue with userName and Api token.**

Answer (score 3):

As shown in [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePc21.png) you need to add the bearer token in the **Username** of the Postman and once you Preview the request you will be able to authenticate to Sonar.

Comment: How do I get Bearer Token? Is it the same as API token/User token that we create from within SonarQube portal? I am really confused.